# $W_n = U - U_n$ where $U \sim \operatorname{uniform}[0, 1]$ and $U_n = \frac{\lfloor nU \rfloor}{n}$.

Tags: probability

Determine the distribution of $W_n$ and find the correlation coefficient $\rho(U, U_n)$.

I'm guessing that $W_n$ has a uniform distribution as well since $U = U - U_n$ in distribution? From there, how would you find $\rho(U, U_n)$?

Comment: If you meant $U$ and $U-U_n$ both have the same distribution, then that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

hint: $W$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1/n)$, try to think why and then proceed with the problem

Comment: Is it because $0 \leq U -U_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ ?

So $W_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: your statements are right, but why does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}W_{n}$ concern you?